Changing user data in my Google Workspace
I need to change the job title for the users on our Google Workspace domain. I have also written a suitable script for this. However, when I execute my script, the users in the GWS area Organisation get the new and correct JobTitle, but the other fields such as Department are empty.
Here is my script:
function myEditUserDatas() {
  var ssID = "1_yDRkyO9kwT-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("EditEmployees ");
  var myLR = sheet.getLastRow();

  for (let i = 2; i <= myLR; i++) {
    var uMail = sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();
    var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(uMail);

    //Datas from GSheet
    var JobFunction = sheet.getRange(i,14).getValue();

    user.organizations = [{
      department: JobDepartment
    }];

    AdminDirectory.Users.update(user, uMail);
  }
}

Does anyone have a tip for me as to what I have overlooked?
Greetings
function myEditUserDatas() {
  var ssID = "1_yDRkyO9kwT-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("EditEmployees ");
  var myLR = sheet.getLastRow();

  for (let i = 2; i <= myLR; i++) {
    var uMail = sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();
    var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(uMail);

    //Datas from GSheet
    var JobFunction = sheet.getRange(i,14).getValue();

    user.organizations = [{
      department: JobDepartment
    }];

    AdminDirectory.Users.update(user, uMail);
  }
}


Could you please share a text table with what your sample data looks like, and what your user objects look like? See how to create a minimal, reproducible example.

"The users in the GWS area Organisation get the new and correct JobTitle": what does "area Organisation" mean? What is "JobTitle"? There is no JobTitle variable in your code. And just in case, you do intend to entirely replace whatever user.organizations contained previously, right?

sorry there is a type-error from my site. In the part "//Datas from GSheet" i mean:
var JobDepartment = sheet.getRange(i,12).getValue();

"Other fields such as Department are empty": that seems normal since in your assignment user.organizations = [{department: JobDepartment}]; you're using a variable JobDepartment that hasn't been initialised. I'm guessing that it should read user.organizations = [{department: JobFunction}]; instead, since you do initialise JobFunction but you never use it.

Updating Organizations in Admin SDK using GAS
You are providing a wrong JSON Payload for the update endpoint. Code provided was created on the assumption that Email is on Col A, Job Title is on Col B, Department is on Col C.
Sample Code:
function updateUserData(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ChangeDependingonYourSheetID");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("NameofYourSheet");
var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,sheet.getLastColumn());
var data = range.getValues();

for(i =0; i<data.length; i++){
 
let options = {"organizations": [
    {
      "title": data[i][1],
     "department": data[i][2]
    }
]}

 let adminResponse = AdminDirectory.Users.update(options,data[i][0]);
 console.log(adminResponse)
}
}

Result:

Reference:
Request Body for Admin SDK
Update User - Admin SDK

In your example, however, the title and the department are also set again. If, for example, I only replace the ‘Title’ field via the script, the ‘Department’ field is always emptied. Does this mean that I cannot replace the fields individually but that I always have to replace the complete ‘block’?

Yes that is right. If you are going to get a child and include it on the payload whatever value that child has will be taken into account. You can take the organizations.title then get it and add it on the payload this goes with the department as well.

However, this is a somewhat suboptimal solution :). But thanks for the help
